# C#: Split string and assign result to multiple string variables

Tags: c#, perl, string, split

I have a string with several fields separated by a specific character, something like this:

> A,B,C

I want to split the string at the commas and assign each resulting field to its own string variable. In Perl I can do that elegantly like this:

```
my ($varA, $varB, $varC) = split (/,/, $string);
```

**What is the simplest and most elegant way to achieve the same result in C#?**

I know that I can split into an array:

```
string[] results = string.Split(',');
```

But then I would have to access the fields via their index, e.g. results[2]. That is difficult to read and error-prone - consider not having 3 buth 30 fields. For that reason I prefer having each field value in its own named variable.

Comment: Not an answer on how to do it with C#, but F# can do pretty much exactly what you want: `let [| a; b; c |] = "1,2,3".Split(',')`

Comment: F# is awesome. I wish it were more popular in commercial settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree. Hiding the split in an Adapter class seems like a good approach and communicates your intent rather well:

```
public class MySplitter
{
     public MySplitter(string split)
     {
         var results = string.Split(',');
         NamedPartA = results[0];
         NamedpartB = results[1];
     }

     public string NamedPartA { get; private set; }
     public string NamedPartB { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, it requires one class per usage scenario of Split because the number of results are fixed as well as the names. I want the names to be flexible.

Comment: I'd say it requires one instance per type that you want to have names for. It's a minor bit of code that makes the consumer code easier to read and interpret.

Comment: Except that I'd expect `MySplitter` to be something that stores the result named parts.  A splitter should just split and return the split parts. Instead, I might consider something more semantic: `Person` that has `First` and `Last` and a static method called `parse` that returns a new instance of `Person`.  `person.First` would make more sense to me than `personSplitter.First`

Answer (score 7):

You can use Tuples (added in .Net 4). [Tuples in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387036.aspx)

This:

```
public class MySplitter
{
     public MySplitter(string split)
     {
         var results = split.Split(',');
         NamedPartA = results[0];
         NamedpartB = results[1];
     }

     public string NamedPartA { get; private set; }
     public string NamedPartB { get; private set; }
}
```

Could be achieved with something like this:

```
public Tuple<string,string> SplitIntoVars(string toSplit)
{
   string[] split = toSplit.Split(',');
   return Tuple.Create(split[0],split[1]);
}
```

With a Tuple  you can use:

```
var x = SplitIntoVars(arr);
// you can access the items like this:    x.Item1 or x.Item2 (and x.Item3 etc.)
```

You can also create a Tuple for using `Tuple<string,int>` etc.

Also... I don't really like out parameters, so you emulate returning multiple values using 
a Tuple (and obviously, also of varying types).
this:

```
public void SplitIntoVariables(string input, out a, out b, out c)
{
    string pieces[] = input.Split(',');
    a = pieces[0];
    b = pieces[1];
    c = pieces[2];
}
```

turns into this:

```
public Tuple<string,string,string> SplitIntoVariables(string[] input)
    {
        string pieces[] = input.Split(',');
        return Tuple.Create(pieces[0],pieces[1],pieces[2]);
    }
```

Other (more imaginative) options could be creating an ExpandoObject (dynamic) that holds your values (something akin to ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC)

Comment: Interesting. Did not know about tuples before.

Comment: One of the reason for not suggesting a Tuple is the fact that result[0] isn't much clearer than tuple.Item1, Item2, etc.... The OP explicitly stated a desire for named values.

Comment: I think it's still better than arrays, as it's not exactly using indexes, and you don't recreate structures that exist in the FW. Either way, I think the best solution would probably involve a solution that's closer to the actual problem, and not something so general as the current question. IMO the most elegant solution (if you cant create a good concrete class) would be something such as a Dynamic Dictionary (like the ViewBag).

Comment: I agree. Other languages have much better answers to this sort of problem (Perl, OCaml, F#). For C#, my approach is the style I'd use. Obviously I'm biased ;)

Answer (score 3):

And who can't resist some Linq insanity!

```
string names = "Joe,Bob,Lucy";
var myVars = names.Split(',').Select((x, index) => Tuple.Create(index,x)).ToDictionary(x => "var" + x.Item1, y => y.Item2);
Debug.WriteLine(myVars["var0"]);
```

Comment: Sooo... Youve got a Dictionary[var+Index] of strings instead of an string array[Index]?

Answer (score 3):

@pnvn has a great idea with the Unpack pattern, but it could be improved to iterate over the enumeration in a single pass, provide defaults past the end of the enumerable and work on any type or size of enumerable in a predictable way.

Here is an example using [C# 7 `out variables` feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables).

```
"A,B,C".Split(',')
    .Unpack(out string varA)
    .Unpack(out string varB);
```

This requires two extension methods, one for the IEnumerable to start, the second on the IEnumerator for each subsequent call.

```
public static IEnumerator<T> Unpack<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, out T item)
{
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        item = enumerator.Current;
        return enumerator;
    }
    item = default(T);
    return null;
}

public static IEnumerator<T> Unpack<T>(this IEnumerator<T> enumerator, out T item)
{
    if (enumerator != null && enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        item = enumerator.Current;
        return enumerator;
    }            
    item = default(T);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or if you just want to avoid the extra variable name for readability sake, you could do something like that (C#7+):

```
public static void Deconstruct<T>(this IList<T> self, out T v1, out T v2) {
    v1 = self.Count > 0 ? self[0] : default;
    v2 = self.Count > 1 ? self[1] : default;
}
```

On another static class where you write your extension methods.
And then use it like:

```
var (a, b) = "1,2".Split(','); // a = "1"; b = "2";
```

Obviously, this can be extended for more than two variables, but unfortunately, you have to write another method as far as I know.

For example:

```
public static class Ex {
    public static void Deconstruct<T>(this IList<T> self, out T v1, out T v2) {
        v1 = self.Count > 0 ? self[0] : default;
        v2 = self.Count > 1 ? self[1] : default;
    }

    public static void Deconstruct<T>(this IList<T> self, out T v1, out T v2, out T v3) {
        v1 = self.Count > 0 ? self[0] : default;
        v2 = self.Count > 1 ? self[1] : default;
        v3 = self.Count > 2 ? self[2] : default;
    }

    public static void Deconstruct<T>(this IList<T> self, out T v1, out T v2, out T v3, out T v4) {
        v1 = self.Count > 0 ? self[0] : default;
        v2 = self.Count > 1 ? self[1] : default;
        v3 = self.Count > 2 ? self[2] : default;
        v4 = self.Count > 3 ? self[3] : default;
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
var (a,_,_,d) = "1a,2b,3c,4d".Split(','); // a = "1a"; d = "4d";
```

As a side effect, now you can deconstruct any array.

```
var (first,second) = new [] { 1,2 }; // first = 1; second = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a one line solution. But, how about an extension method with an additional `out` parameter?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Unpack<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, out T target)
{
    target = source.First();
    return source.Skip(1);
}
```

Then, you could use the method like this.

```
string values = "aaa,bbb,ccc";
string x, y, z;
values.Split(',')
    .Unpack(out x)
    .Unpack(out y)
    .Unpack(out z);
```

Note that the `Unpack` method enumerates the sequence twice. So, I'd use it only if the data in the `IEnumerable` object is repeatable.

I didn't care to check the performance of the method because I thought that normally we would not unpack a large array.

Of course, you could use `ref` modifier instead of `out`, and the usage would be different.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way in C# to do a multiple assignment like you can in Perl; however, there are multiple solutions to get the data into each variable via a normal path.

Comment: Well, what is the most elegant way to get the data into each variable?

Comment: In my opinion, Rich Melton (above) posted a good solution - it abstracts the 'crap' (the splitting) behind a complex object and then names the resulting output variables into properties.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resist adding to the ridiculousness :) Please don't use this "solution", at least not as-is.

```
static class StringExtensions
{
   private static readonly Func<object, string, Action<object, object>> GetSetter =
       (o1, n) => (o2, v) => o1.GetType().GetProperty(n).SetValue(o2, v, null);

   public static T AssignFromCSV<T>(this string csv, T obj, string[] propertyNames)
   {
       var a = csv.Split(new[] {','});
       for (var i = 0 ; i < propertyNames.Length; i++)
       {
           GetSetter(obj, propertyNames[i])(obj, a[i]);
       }
       return obj ;
   }
}

class TargetClass
{
   public string A { get; set; }

   public string B { get; set; }

   public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var target = "1,2,3".AssignFromCSV(new TargetClass(), new[] {"A", "B", "C"}) ;
```