# How can i check and split strings which contains comma,backslash,and(&),hyphen

Tags: c#

I have a string (for eg:blue,rose/yellow-white).So i want to check for the symbols  and need to split all these individual strings after symbols.
ie after spliting i need to get,

```
blue
rose
yellow
white
```

seperatedley.how can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Split string and assign result to multiple string variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266207/c-split-string-and-assign-result-to-multiple-string-variables)

Comment: How about `str.Split(',', '/', '-')`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Split(char[])` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
var s = "blue,rose/yellow-white";
var array = s.Split(new char[] { ',', '/', '-' });
```

[image]

This method returns `string[]` and you can access your strings with their index numbers like `array[0]`, `array[1]` or you can iterate them with `foreach` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need this

```
var yourString = "blue,rose/yellow-white";
var delimiters = new[] { ',', '/','-'}; //You can add more delimiters as you required
var result = yourString.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var item in result)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string words = "blue;yellow-white,red";
char [] delimeters = {';','-',','};
string[] splittedWords = words.Split(delimeters);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split on any non-character you can use [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Regex.Split("blue,rose/yellow-white", @"[^\s]");
```

`@` makes the following string a literal string (does not try to escape `\s`); `[^\s]` is Regex for "not a character" (aA-zZ).

Answer (score 0):

split takes params, so this is the probably the cleanest syntax

```
var list = "blue,rose/yellow-white";
var result = list.split(',','/','-');
```